# How do I detect computer suspension using python?

Tags: python

I'm making an alarm using python, and I'm using time.sleep() to wait for alarm time. But if I suspend my computer, the sleep will suspend too, causing the alarm to sound after what was intended if I turn the computer on again.

I need a way for the program to detect when the computer is going to be suspended, and if not possible, to detect it has been suspended, so I can implement the timer correctly.

How can this be done with python?

Comment: I think this might depend on the operating system you are using. What do you use?

Comment: Instead of sleeping for a long time you can sleep for a short time and check the time.

Comment: I'm using Linux. Sleeping for a short time and checking will increase the processing cost a lot... is there another way to do it? Even not using time.sleep()...

Comment: @lapisdecor What's your Python version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easily to detect if it was *likely* suspended:

```
before = datetime.now()
sleep(1)
after = datetime.now()

if (after - before).total_seconds() > X:
   # suspended
```

`after - before` will never be exactly 1 second, but they should not be significantly larger than 1 second. You can play around to find best X.

Comment: Is this answer ok, lapisdecor? I think the computational overhead of this solution is not too high, is it?

Comment: this would require that I knew beforehand that there's been a computer supension

Comment: @lapisdecor no it does not. You can check it post factum. If computer was suspended then X will be very large, possibly minutes.

Comment: @andrey so you sugest I do this in another process (since I already have a time.sleep() process running)? How would you implement it?

Comment: I think I'm getting it. I wold sleep many times for a short time and check the time after each sleep, is that it? Wouldn't that change my clock?

Comment: @lapisdecor no do it in the same process. wrap this around your sleep. This is a way to detect that suspension happened after timer expired. You don't need to sleep many times. Sleep once for how much you need and handle suspension afterwards (if it happens)

Comment: @Andrey the thing is I need to know if suspension happens while my sleep is still active, so I can correct the delta. Not just just after sleep finishes. What am I missing here?...

Comment: @lapisdecor if you want to do it while your sleep is active then you indeed need to split it up into shorter sleeps and apply same logic. If 1 small sleep suddenly becomes significantly longer than iit should have been it means that computer was suspended.

Comment: @Andrey I think I will divide the problem into two checking suspension only if timer takes more than a certain amount. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, you can do it like this:

```
import win32com.client

colMonitoredEvents = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator").ConnectServer(".", "root\cimv2").ExecNotificationQuery("Select * from Win32_PowerManagementEvent")

while True:
    objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent()
    if objLatestEvent.EventType == 4:
        pass #do your stuff here
```

Event based, run it indefinitely with low CPU usage and do stuff when the event ID is 4. Note that the action should be very quick or likely it will not complete before entering sleep.

Event 7 is used instead when resuming from sleep.